# How to have Qr code option in QT application

Tags: qt, qml

i'm working for a domotic app , user has acces to both mobile and home screen app : mobile when he is not home . for more security , i want that when user doing off for his home screen a QR code showed up (there are people who are boring from log in interface so it's easy for them only scan the QR code ) , so user could scan with his phone the code on the screen .
i already read about ZXing library in c++ for both QR code and barcodes

**problem i think i'm going to face and i need some ideas and solutions :**

- qt in a multiplatform language so both mobile and home screen have same interfaces for how could i made two differents options like mobile has ability to scan and other screen to show the QR code , is there any option in qt to know which plateform m using ?

(m trying to do like wattsApp and web wattsApp with the Qr code option ) is this available in qml ? and how could i do this ?
PS: i already had a look about the QR code option in qt , but for the problem i talk above i didn't find.

Comment: Yes, as you point out there's ZXing library that has reasonably performance for QR codes. For commercial usage, we have exposed one of the C++ ZXing ports to QML, but, it was a non-trivial exercise. Initially we used QImage as an input, but, later, found it was better to hook into QAbstractVideoFilter for direct in-memory access to a live Camera feed. Some of the other barcode types, your mileage may vary. Also, Android and iOS have ML (AI-based) barcode scanning which has better performance and accuracy.

Comment: yes I had discovered some of the most important points of the ZXing scale, but how has having an app changed depending on the platform?

Answer (score 0):

In Qt5.x you can implement QAbstractVideoFilter with the aim of processing QVideoFrame. In Qt6.x you can implement a QVideoSink for your QMediaCaptureSession. The code is non-trivial, so, I will give you the high level.

My preferred implementation is to actually keep the native C++ as small as possible, so, we're talking as thin wrappers as you can to marshall the in-memory video frames to the respective barcode handlers. Whilst it's possible to have #ifdef platform checks in C++ I prefer to minimize native code and do the platform switching in QML.

I would implement something like:

```
BarcodeReader.ZXing 1.0 - a QML wrapper to C++ ZXing library
BarcodeReader.Android 1.0 - a QML wrapper to the Android Vision library
BarcodeReader.iOS 1.0 - a QML wrapper to iOS Vision Framework
```

The last two libraries, of course, are optional, since, you can get your cross-platform implementation based on ZXing alone. However, as I mentioned in the comments the performance and accuracy of ZXing pales compared to the others.

If you implement all 3, then, I highly recommend the use of FileSelectors so that the optimal BarcodeScanner.qml is chosen for Android and iOS but it'll default to the ZXing library for all other platforms:

```
BarcodeScanner.qml // Camera + VideoOutput + ZXing
+android/BarcodeScanner.qml // Camera + VideoOutput + Android Vision
+ios/BarcodeScanner.qml // Camera + VideoOutput + iOS Vision Framework
```

You always have the option to fall back to ZXing if your want on Android and iOS which is why it is helpful to have all the implementations there ready for you to import, but, generally, the wrapper is all you need to abstract the library.

This is an overall architecture, and, unfortunately, I am not in the position to share any code on how to do this, but, I can say that this approach has been tested and works.